# How to animate a line in canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, gsap

I am trying to animate a line using canvas. I want to use TimelineLite to handle the animation.  How would I do this?  I know that in TimelineLite, the Timelines look like this:

```
var timeline = new TimelineLite();
timeline.to(target, duration, vars, position);
```

The points exist in a JSON file, and the file is correctly being brought in with AJAX.  I want the line to start at the points x1 & y1, keep x2, as the same value, and animate it to the y2 position.  So I basically want it to grow from x1-y1 to x2-y2.

**JS**

```
function animateLines(name, stroke, width, x1, y1, x2, y2){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.strokeStyle = stroke;
    ctx.stroke;
    console.log(x2);
}

for(var i = 0; i < animated_lines.length; i++){
    animateLines(animated_lines[i].name, animated_lines[i].stroke, animated_lines[i].width, animated_lines[i].x1, animated_lines[i].y1, animated_lines[i].x2, animated_lines[i].y2);
}
```

**JSON**

```
"animated_lines": [
    {
        "name": "Test",
        "stroke": "red",
        "width": 3,
        "x1": 0,
        "y1": 0,
        "x2": 0,
        "y2": 50
    }
]
```

So my question is really a multi-part one.  How do I go about animating the line using canvas?  How do I animate the line based on the `name` in the `animateLine()` function?

Answer (score 0):

**`TimelineLite`** uses the `element` to transform the targeted values of that element.

You can watch the update progress of the transform using `onUpdate` over time and animate your line based on that value.

```js
timeline.eventCallback('onUpdate',function(data){
    var progress = this.progress();
    // Do animation calls here!
});
```

#### Here is a working example code snippet

I am transitioning the canvas opacity during the timeline and animating the canvas.

```js
var timeline = new TimelineLite();
var mainCanvas = document.getElementById("ctx");
var ctx = mainCanvas.getContext("2d");
var temp = document.createElement('div');

var animated_lines = [{
  "name": "Red",
  "stroke": "#ff0000",
  "width": 3,
  "x1": 50,
  "y1": 50,
  "x2": 100,
  "y2": 100
},{
  "name": "Green",
  "stroke": "#00ff00",
  "width": 2,
  "x1": 50,
  "y1": 20,
  "x2": 100,
  "y2": 100
}];

function createLine(line, progress) {
  ctx.lineWidth = line.width;
  ctx.strokeStyle = line.stroke;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(line.x1, line.y1);
  ctx.lineTo(line.x2, line.y2*progress);
  ctx.stroke();
}
 
console.log('ctx', ctx);
timeline.from('#ctx', 10, { opacity: 0 });

timeline.eventCallback('onUpdate',function(){
  var progress = this.progress();
  //console.log(progress);
  ctx.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , mainCanvas.width, mainCanvas.height );
  for (var i = 0; i < animated_lines.length; i++) {
    createLine(animated_lines[i], progress);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/71ug4n6f/1/) the kind of effect you were looking to produce or something similar?

JS of which is as belows:

```
var width,height,centerX,centerY,canvas,context;
var delayFactor=.06,duration=1.2,ease=Elastic.easeOut,destIncrement=200,strokeWidth=2;
var timeline=new TimelineMax({paused:true,repeat:-1,yoyo:true,repeatDelay:duration*.5});
var animatedLines=[
    {name:'Test',stroke:'red',width:strokeWidth,x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:destIncrement},
    {name:'Test',stroke:'green',width:strokeWidth,x1:0,y1:0,x2:destIncrement*.5,y2:destIncrement*.5},
    {name:'Test',stroke:'blue',width:strokeWidth,x1:0,y1:0,x2:destIncrement,y2:0},
    {name:'Test',stroke:'red',width:strokeWidth,x1:0,y1:0,x2:destIncrement*.5,y2:-destIncrement*.5},
    {name:'Test',stroke:'green',width:strokeWidth,x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:-destIncrement},
    {name:'Test',stroke:'blue',width:strokeWidth,x1:0,y1:0,x2:-destIncrement*.5,y2:-destIncrement*.5},
    {name:'Test',stroke:'red',width:strokeWidth,x1:0,y1:0,x2:-destIncrement,y2:0},
    {name:'Test',stroke:'green',width:strokeWidth,x1:0,y1:0,x2:-destIncrement*.5,y2:destIncrement*.5}
];
function init(){
    initCanvas();
    initLines();
    populateTimeline();
    timeline.play();
    TweenLite.ticker.addEventListener('tick',render);
}
function populateTimeline(){
    var length=animatedLines.length,currentLine;
    for(var i=0; i<length; i+=1){
        currentLine=animatedLines[i];
        timeline.to(currentLine,duration,{destX:currentLine.x2,destY:currentLine.y2,ease:ease},i*delayFactor);
    }
}
function initLines(){
    var length=animatedLines.length,currentLine;
    for(var i=0; i<length; i+=1){
        currentLine=animatedLines[i];
        currentLine.destX=currentLine.x1;
        currentLine.destY=currentLine.y1;
    }
}
function initCanvas(){
    canvas=document.querySelector('canvas');
    context=canvas.getContext('2d');
    width=canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
    height=canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
    centerX=width*.5;
    centerY=height*.5;
}
function drawLine(currentLine){
    context.lineWidth=currentLine.width;
    context.strokeStyle=currentLine.stroke;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(centerX+currentLine.x1,centerY+currentLine.y1);
    context.lineTo(centerX+currentLine.destX,centerY+currentLine.destY);
    context.stroke();
}
function render(){
    var length=animatedLines.length;
    context.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    for(var i=0; i<length; i+=1){ drawLine(animatedLines[i]); }
}
init();
```

The trick is to introduce two new variables into each *Line* of your `animatedLines`, namely `destX` and `destY`, and set their initial values to that of your `x1` and `y1` respectively, defined under the `initLines();` function. And then make them increment towards your `x2` and `y2` values using `TimelineMax` which happens in the `populateTimeline();` function.

Go ahead and take a look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/71ug4n6f/1/) to take it further.

Hope this is helpful to you in some way.