# Animating a line

Tags: jquery, css, gsap

I have a line object that I'm trying to animate using TimelineLite.  Since the first parameter in a timeline function is the element, how would I do this using the line object?

```
function animatedLine(name, x1, y1, x2, y2, stroke, width, duration){
    this.name = name;
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.y2 = y2;
    this.stroke = stroke;
    this.width = width;
    this.duration = duration;
}
var line1 = new animatedLine("R01", 0, 0, 0, 100, "black", 3, 3);
```

So basically, the line is going to have a starting point of x1, y1.  Or, `({"left": x1, "top": y1})`  How do I make the line animate vertically so that the height equals the value of `y2` and the width of the line equals the value of `width`?

Comment: It's really unclear of what you are trying to do. How are you trying to animate a line as an image? Please provide a fiddle example.

Comment: I'm assuming this is an SVG? I'm doubtful you could use JS to animate an SVG actually used as an `img` element...but I'd be interested to see if you can.

Comment: crap.  Sorry, I meant line, not image.  I'm updating the question.

Comment: @Paulie_D actually, it's Canvas, not SVG.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a response to something similar a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29703593/3344111.

Not sure if this is the kind of thing you were looking for.

Tahir.

Comment: I'm using TimelineLite, but I was hoping there was a way to do it without using GreenSock.

Comment: Well TimelineLite in this case is doing nothing but progressing `destX` and `destY` from `x1` & `y1` to `x2` & `y2` respectively. Canvas is still rendering the whole thing as you can see in the `render` method. So it is possible to replace GSAP with you controlling the progress of the said variables. But you will lose the `ease` with which variables will progress. Unless you want to write custom eases yourself as well. Why do you want to not use TimelineLite anymore by the way?

Comment: I think TimelineLite and all GSAP products are all great.  I just want to learn how to do these things myself.

Comment: They are their for a reason of course. But if you really want to dig, I think a good starting point for these canvas related animating things is the [Coding Math](http://www.codingmath.com/) video tutorial series by [Keith Peters](https://twitter.com/bit101).

Comment: Yeah, Like I said, I really do love GSAP's products and have no issues with using frameworks like that.  I just want to expand my knowledge base and skill set by learning how to do it myself.  Thanks for the link, I'll check it out.